# Is there a way to render a razor view located in another project

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qey1C.png)

i have a two classlibrary project. cl2 is reference of cl1. i want to call cl2 view from cl1 controller

```
public class AboutController
    {
        public IActionResult RenderView()
        {
            return View("~/cl2/Views/AboutView.cshtml", model);
        }

    }
```

getting error like this
{"ClassName":"System.InvalidOperationException","Message":"The view '~/cl2/Views/AboutView.cshtml' was not found}

Comment: I've never seen a console app use the razor view engine.

Comment: @SamAxe mvc project

Comment: You created a couple of MVC apps called ConsoleApp1 and ConsoleApp2?  How odd.

Comment: Anyhow.. ASP.NET Core MVC added View Libraries in 2.x I think.. mabey 3.x.

Comment: @SamAxe The projectB and projectA are  a class library mvc project.  how to call views located in the  projectB

Comment: Hi @Vetrii,Why did you want to render the view which in the other project?

Comment: @Rena view is the common for all other project